# HTML + PHPMailer + PDF -> WordPress

Tags: html, wordpress, forms, nginx, phpmailer

I am struggling since days now and I cannot find a solution for one of my projects.
I was asked to create a multilingual HTML form that sends the input data both as an HTML email and a generated PDF (fPDF) as an attachment. So far I finished everything in a XAMPP/localhost environment, however the last step was to upload it to a website. And this is where the headache comes in - it is a WordPress-hosted one. My problem is, that so far I couldn't get the email function working.

- I tried uploading the files to the WP File Manager, from where it loads the forms perfectly, but when it comes to the php file handling, it results in a **http 500** error message.
- Somewhere I read, that if the phpmailer file is placed within the wp-includes folder, it will work, however, I received a different error message there, it was an **403 Forbidden nginx** message.

Could someone please advise on how to proceed?
Thank you

Comment: This is a very loosely defined question and you're unlikely to get good answers as a result. You need to do some basic investigation (e.g. read your error log) to see what's behind those 500 errors. It does help to cooperate with WordPress when using PHPMailer within it. You may find [this article](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Using-PHPMailer-in-WordPress) useful.

Comment: Presumably you have asked your hosting company for help: this is their responsibility. You can also use a SMTP plugin and an emailing service. The sendgrid.com service has a generous free tier.

Comment: Hello @Synchro,
Thank you for your answer, couldn't fetch the logs from Wordpress, as I don't know how , but tried the approaches that were in your given link, the problem with these plugins is, that they do not support building a PDF file in the same email. At this point, I guess I will turn to the hosting company.

Comment: Hello @O.Jones,
Thank you for your reply,
Unfortunately, I have tried multiple mailer providers in the plugin list of Wordpress, but none of them supported the approach we need for this to work. As Others already mentioned here, I guess the best approach would be to contact the hosting provider.

Comment: You may want to ask another question, or [edit] this one to explain further. It sounds like you have developed a standalone web app to send the contents of a form both as an HTML -formatted email message and as a PDF attachment to that same message.Now you need to integrate that standalone app into a WordPress site.Is that correct?

Comment: That's correct. The email contains both the HTML formatted inputs of the form with some extra text AND the pdf file attachment, which basically contains the same input data from the form, just in a different format.